# Get size of Buffer

Tags: opengl

I want to copy the data from one buffer to another with [glCopyBufferSubData](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glCopyBufferSubData.xhtml). However I don't know the size of the buffer I'm copying from. How do I get the size?

Comment: The buffer is not created by you?

Comment: Yes it is, but I do not store the size in a seperate variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this, you simply need to call [`glGetBufferParameteriv (...)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetBufferParameteriv.xml) with the appropriate enum.

In this case, you want the size of the buffer object, so use `GL_BUFFER_SIZE` for `value`.

You have not mentioned what role the buffer object is serving (e.g. what it is currently bound to), but I am going to assume it is a Vertex Buffer Object for simplicity (so `target` is `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`).

**Thus we have:**

```
GLint size = 0;

glBindBuffer          (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer_obj);
glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &size);
```

You are limited to a size of 4 GiB prior to GL 3.2, though I doubt this really matters as you would surely hit some other limitation first. Neverthless, `glGetBufferParameteri64v (...)` exists for buffers larger than 4 GiB.

Comment: Does it return number of elements or does it return bytes?