# Correct use of glCopyBufferSubData

Tags: opengl

This is a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22077137/get-size-of-buffer) question.

I have set up my Copy Constructor like this:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &m_vertexBuffer);
glGenBuffers(1, &m_colorBuffer);
glGenBuffers(1, &m_indexBuffer);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vertexArray);

glBindVertexArray(m_vertexArray);

GLint size = 0;

glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, other.m_indexBuffer);
glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &size);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_indexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glCopyBufferSubData(other.m_indexBuffer, m_indexBuffer, 0, 0, size);

glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, other.m_vertexBuffer);
glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &size);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vertexBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glCopyBufferSubData(other.m_vertexBuffer, m_vertexBuffer, 0, 0, size);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *) 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, other.m_colorBuffer);
glGetBufferParameteriv(GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &size);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_colorBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glCopyBufferSubData(other.m_colorBuffer, m_colorBuffer, 0, 0, size);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void *) 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

However, size is 0 after the first glGetBufferParameteriv call. Does it work differently on index buffers? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not pass the actual buffer object names to `glCopyBufferSubData (...)`, you pass the enum for the location the buffer objects are bound to. Interestingly, there is no error state defined for what you tried to do, but realistically it should be creating a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error.

You are on the right track with using `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER`, etc. That is a special binding location that will not disrupt anything else that is currently using a bound buffer object, but you shot yourself in the foot when you started passing buffer object names.

The simplest solution would be to use `GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER` for the object you are copying from and `GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER` for the new object you are creating.

#### Here are a few slightly modified lines of code that show this:

```c
glBindBuffer           (GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, other.m_indexBuffer);
glGetBufferParameteriv (GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_BUFFER_SIZE, &size);

glBindBuffer           (GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, m_indexBuffer);
glBufferData           (GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, size, nullptr, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glCopyBufferSubData    (GL_COPY_READ_BUFFER, GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER, 0, 0, size);
```

Comment: If I change the lines like you suggested, I get a segmentation fault. Also, size is still zero after the glGetBufferParameteriv call.

Comment: Well, you probably actually needed to have the destination buffer bound to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` in that case. Go ahead and replace all instances of `GL_COPY_WRITE_BUFFER` with `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` in the code sample I listed and see if that changes anything. I wasn't sure if you were intentionally binding to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` or not intitially.

Comment: Nope, I still get a segmentation fault. I think the main problem is that size is zero. Any thoughts on that? EDIT: But thanks so far!!

Comment: It worked, my error was that with some objects I didn't have indices.

Comment: Nevermind, it only worked with objects that don't use index buffers. Copying an object with an index buffer seems to work, but drawing it results in a segmentation fault.

Comment: Ok, that was another error, what you proposed worked. Thanks a lot!